# "Blue Windows" screen when a hard drive from a "dead" machine is replaced?

Tags: windows, laptop, installation

I am given a "dead" ACER Aspire 5733 Model PEW71 laptop. I opened the laptop and see no hard drive in it.

So I slid in a hard drive of my own, and this laptop goes to the "blue windows" screen and asks if I want to repair etc.. problem is, doesn't matter what I choose, it won't do anything past that. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yes - cannibalize it for parts.

Comment: Also, you can try to reinstall windows. It may actually fix the laptop if its only a software defect.

Comment: Or easier, install a Linux distro, or even run it from USB *without* installing anything. Installing Ubuntu, for example, can be done in ~15 minutes from a Live USB. Also, Windows requires licensing, and with a drive from another PC, you might need to buy a license.

Comment: What version of windows are we dealing with?

Comment: You probably just need to install a new fresh OS. While Windows theoretically supports changing systems, effectively, this ability is pretty limited, and nearly always it is better just to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Also, what exactly did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Below windows 10 you would have to inject drivers for the SATA controller.

Although this is the most critical driver, you will definitely need to install a bunch of other drivers later.

1. Get the drivers, and extract them as you need the *.inf files and related.  EXE files won't work.
2. Place drivers on a USB thumb drive
3. Boot from a Windows DVD or USB
4. Command prompt
5. inject the drivers   `dism /image:C: /Add-drivers /drivers:d:\drivers /recurse`

You will likely have to change the c: and d: to match whatever the drive letters happen to be on your system.